# The code after await operation is not executing

Tags: c#, async-await, jsonconvert

I'm writing a xamarin forms app and I'm using an API that I created. I've followed a tutorial to consume the Api but the code after the async operation never gets executed, it jumps out to the main function.

The code is exactly like the one in the tutorial I've been following. I didn't find any info since there is no error message.

```
private async void ChecarCredenciales(string username, string password)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var url = "http://localhost:57008/api/operadores/" + username;
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Lecturista = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Operadores>(response);
        }
```

The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` never gets executed so the `Lecturista` variable never gets initialized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "jumps out of the main function", can you please clarify **exactly** what this means?

Comment: Don't use `async void`, use `async Task` for the method's signature. Also, have you tried wrapping this code block in a try-catch to see if you are receiving an exception?

Comment: You may be better of finding another tutorial - one that recommends `async void` is not necessary good (unless it is to show event handling)

Comment: @RyanWilson I did and I'm not getting any exception, I have the exact same result with async Task.

Comment: Does "main function" mean the `Main` method of `Program`?

Comment: Chances are that you have a deadlock because you are mixing async with .Result or with other signatures that return void instead of Task. You will have to create an [mcve] if you really want.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes as if there is a return after the await operation, sorry.

Comment: @HectorFlores indeed `await` is essentially `return`... But without real [MCVE] it is hard to see what can cause problem you see (as code itself is reasonable... ignoring `async void` and generally useless `.ConfigureAwait(false)`)

Comment: @HectorFlores I agree with Igor about  a deadlock may be taking place due to mixing `async void` and `async Task`, this is why I suggested using `async Task` as it should help eliminate the deadlock problem.

Comment: The code after the `await` does not execute before you return to the caller because that's what `await` means! The definition of `await` is "if the task is complete, execute the code after the await; if the task is not complete, defer the execution of the code after the await until the task is complete and return to the caller". If you expected something different to happen, that's because you have a false belief about what `await` means. You should change that belief!

Comment: You've described a program that behaves correctly, and you have not asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: If your **Main** method does not wait for tasks to complete, then yes, your program will terminate. However, you have not given conclusive evidence that this is what you're doing.

Comment: @EricLippert I've seen form multiple sources people adding code after the await operation. I'm also using it for waiting a `DisplayAlert` response and the code after it's working just fine. I think the problem is with `GetStringAsync`. I'll try on another PC in case it has to do with my installation since nothing seems to be working. Thanks to everyone

Comment: @HectorFlores nothing will work until you change your code and change `async void` to `async Task`, and then await `ChecarCredenciales`. I bet none of those sources use `async void`, or if they do, they do so only in event handlers

Answer (score 2):

First as other already commented change your method to be `async Task` rather like `private async Task ChecarCredenciales(string username, string password){`

Second in your `await` block you are saying  to continue on a Threadpool thread context rather on the same synchronization context by doing `ConfigureAwait(false);`. I would suggest you continue on the same context since on the next step you are requiring the resultant data

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
Lecturista = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Operadores>(response);
```

Comment: I got the same result. I uploaded a simple example [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bsCUrFDi6viXobkoJH7cU79PTVCAvKnU). since the Api is in my localhost it won't work but it should at least get an error right?

Comment: @HectorFlores no, if there was no error and your application terminated *before* `GetStringAsync` completed. That's the problem with `async void`. It *can't* be awaited. Don't post links to zip files though. Post *your code* in the question itself. You shouldn't need more than 10-15 lines to demonstrate what you want. If you use `async void` though, the problem is clear. *Your own code* doesn't wait for `GetStringAsync` to complete before terminating the application